# Even after a year Google is not showing breadcrumbs with the site name instead of the URL in search results

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

We have had this for a year now and the Site Name still isnt showing in the search results breadcrumb, just the URL.

Can someone take a look at my page and mark up and verify my site looks OK?

[Site Homepage](https://basketball.exposureevents.com/)

```html
 <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "WebSite",
    "name" : "Exposure Basketball",
    "alternateName" : "Exposure Basketball Events",
    "url" : "http://basketball.exposureevents.com",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://basketball.exposureevents.com/youth-basketball-events?searchtoken={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "name=search_term_string"
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Google Search result]

Comment: I did a search for site:basketball.exposureevents.com and found About 145,000 results (0.56 seconds). I realize that is not what you are talking about, however, what you mean by Site Name is not clear. Can you clarify your expectations? It is likely we already have your question answered.

Comment: Do you know what a Google Site Name is? The link below provides it and expert SEO people will know what it is.  Thanks. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename

Comment: I get a 404 for the link you provided. Still, I feel you missed my point. What search are you conducting? For example, are you searching for the domain name with or without the TLD?

Comment: @closetnoc he is talking about [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename). Mike@ I think the problem is you're using very general name like basketball, exposure which is already used by other webmaster and it's very generic name.

Comment: @Goyllo Thanks for a working link. I understood what the name is, however, since the SERP results are so search query independent, I wanted to know what queries the OP is using. I did a few searches and I do not see what I would expect. The code checks out okay. On the page you linked, there are 4 bullet points to pay attention to. That could be the key. The OP may want to experiment with changing the site name and/or even removing the potentialAction to see what they get. Unfortunately Google is not too helpful in dissecting the problem. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm going to change it to `Exposure Events` for now instead of `Exposure Basketball`.  I have replicated sites but different sports with subdomains so I hope they don't conflict.

Comment: Mike, sorry but that's name is also generic. What if I have also that kind of website name? Do you think google will agree to display it? like exposure events > X vs Y > live score . That kind of breadcrumb/navigation is very hard to get for many site, specially your is very generic, I don't think you should waste your time on it.

Comment: It is not generic when it's my freaking domain name buddy. I think Google is smart enough to know your site is a fraud using our name.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone take a look at my page and mark up and verify my site looks OK?

Yes, I can verify that your structured data for the Site Name is correctly formatted.

[image: WebSite > name is correctly marked up]

You can verify this for yourself by using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool here:

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fbasketball.exposureevents.com%2F

However, one thing that *may* be causing an issue is your Organization name does not match your WebSite name:

[image: Organization name does not match WebSite name]

Consider updating your schema to the following:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "WebSite",
    "name" : "Exposure Basketball Events",
    "alternateName" : "Exposure Basketball",
    "url" : "http://basketball.exposureevents.com",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://basketball.exposureevents.com/youth-basketball-events?searchtoken={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "name=search_term_string"
        }
    }
</script>
```

and update the NAP in the footer to match:

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" class="span3 clearfix" data-bind="with: site.subscription">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>

    <p>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div itemprop="name">Exposure Basketball Events</div>
                <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <div itemprop="streetAddress">1877 Douglass Blvd</div>
                    <span><span itemprop="addressLocality">Louisville, Kentucky</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">40205</span> US</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:info@exposureevents.com">info@exposureevents.com</a> | <span itemprop="telephone">502-354-8897</span>
            <meta itemprop="url" content="http://basketball.exposureevents.com" />
            <meta itemprop="logo" content="http://basketball.exposureevents.com/assets/files/0" />
        </p>
    <p>

    </p>
        <ul>
            <li class="social">
                <a itemprop="sameAs" title="Like us on Facebook" class="btn btn-small" target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/exposurebasketballevents"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
                <a itemprop="sameAs" title="Follow us on Twitter" class="btn btn-small" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/exposurebball"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
                <a itemprop="sameAs" title="Follow us on Google +" class="btn btn-small" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/106387783458008299176"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Best of luck!